# Java system variables on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows

I have installed a few Java versions on my system. `C:\Program Files\Java`

`jdk1.7.0_80
jdk1.8.0_20
jdk1.8.0_60
jre1.8.0_60
jre7`.

Now, I recognized in my system variable `PATH` the folder

`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;`

(on the first position!) which links to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\`.

The `JAVA_HOME` points to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80`.

The `PATH` variable contains further `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`.

This is contrary, isn't it?

If I execute the `java -version` in `cmd` it points to the version `1.8.0`:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Why did Java install both ways:

- Add `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` (which points to version `1.8.0` to `PATH`
- Set `%JAVA_HOME%` which points to an older version

Isn't it a bit "dirty"?

Comment: As far as I know, the java installer doesn't set `JAVA_HOME`, I guess you did it yourself, or another tool did it for you.

Comment: I remove the `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` from the PATH every time I install/upgrade Java, because I don't necessarily want the last-installed version to be my default version. I then set `JAVA_HOME` and add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the path instead, like you did. Conflict avoided, and I'm in control. *<wicked laugh>*